# Does stack size grow during runtime?

Tags: c, heap-memory, stack-memory

I wonder if stack size can grow like heap does during runtime?

Comment: Uh, sorry Rachel, I don't think this is really about data structures. Edit reverted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The amount of stack *used* certainly increases, as you allocate local variables and make function calls. Whether the stack's *maximum size* can grow is technically undefined, but in practice is generally constant. You can make the constant bigger with a flag to the OS, but usually each thread gets a certain size of stack. When you use too much, it's a stack overflow.

Comment: Is there command to see the stack size that is determined by the OS ?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? When asking a question, tell us your goal, not your plan.

Comment: @tsubasa: On Windows the stack size is part of the PE header in the image file. To inspect the stack size in an image use dumpbin /headers.

Answer (score 3):

The stack size actually allocated *can* grow on modern desktop operating systems.

In practice it is implemented in terms of the memory management unit. As memory is accessed beyond the current committed pages of the stack, new memory pages are committed in. Only the pages that are actually used (plus one guard page usually) are used in RAM. Maximum stack space can be controlled through system resource limits. For example on POSIX.1-2001 you can query the process maximum stack size with `getrlimit()`.

On the other hand, old operating systems and many embedded systems, lacking a hardware-based memory management unit, do set a fixed limit on the stack size.

Comment: Does this mean the allocated stack size can grow during the runtime if the program uses more stack memory? Then why the "stack overflow" happens? Though we can set a larger stack size before running the program.

Comment: @starriet 
For the stack overflow to happen, you do not need to enter more data than the size of the entire stack. If you have a character type variable which needs one byte of memory space, and the user somehow inputs two bytes of data then that will cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: @Newbie Is it really called "stack" overflow..? Anyway, the situation that the entire stack is overflowed can happen, right? Also, what about the accepted answer? It says the stack size is usually constant, and that's true for Linux or Windows. (although the user can modify that constant, as I mentioned above.)

Comment: @starriet, Thanks for raising the "flag". I forgot that I was talking about stack overflow, not buffer overflow. So, I mixed up stack overflow with buffer overflow. Sorry, I cannot edit my previous comment.
I'm not sure about _laalto_'s claim that "The stack size actually allocated can grow on ..." during **runtime**. If the MMU increases the stack size automatically then, as you mentioned, stack overflow shouldn't happen unless the available space is limited by other factors like the size of the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the executable stack size is defind by the compiler/linker.. so you can change it but not on runtime.
You can change the stack size of a thread.
+ everything is compiler and os specific, so there is no single answer here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can remember stacks generally operate under the assumption that they exist in a contiguous memory range.  Basically the expect the next stack frame to be in the next bit of memory (this helps it run faster not having to do instruction look up).  Like others have said it is possible but i don't think it is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

A thread's stack space is set by the compiler.  My compiler will reserve 2Mb of space.  And will commit 1 Mb.

Of course you can change your compilers default stack size, or you can start a new thread with a larger stack size by calling CreateThread.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -2):

yes. i think the answers is true

Comment: But it answers the question, which does not give much information either.